# How to create partial download in twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

How do you create multiple HTTPDownloader instance with partial download asynchronously? and does it assemble the file automatically after all download is done?

Answer (score 3):

You must use Range HTTP header:

> Range. Request only part of an entity.
>   Bytes are numbered from 0.    Range:
>   bytes=500-999

Ie. If you want download 1000 file in 4 parts, you will starts 4 downloads:

1. 0-2499
2. 2500-4999
3. 5000-7499
4. 7500-9999

And then simply join data from responses.

To check file size you can use HEAD method:

> HEAD Asks for the response identical
>   to the one that would correspond to a
>   GET request, but without the response
>   body. This is useful for retrieving
>   meta-information written in response
>   headers, without having to transport
>   the entire content.

Comment: I've been looking at the HTTPDownloader class but I only see a gotHeader method. Is it the same thing? Also, can you give me an example code of how to request for the HEAD in twisted?

Comment: I'm not twisted programmer, but something like:

    getPage(url, headers={'range': 'bytes=500-999'})

should do the job.

Also you can use:

    getPage(url, method='HEAD')

but I don't know what will be result (again I'm not twisted programmer).