# Download A Single File Using Multiple Threads

Tags: python, download, urllib2, fedora

I'm trying to create a 'Download Manager' for Linux that lets me download one single file using multiple threads. This is what I'm trying to do :

1. Divide the file to be downloaded into different parts by specifying an offset
2. Download the different parts into a temporary location
3. Merge them into a single file.

Steps 2 and 3 are solvable, and it is at Step #1 that I'm stuck. How do I specify an offset while downloading a file?

Using something along the lines of `open("/path/to/file", "wb").write(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())` does not let me specify a starting point to read from. Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: Why do you want to download using multiple threads? The download won't be any quicker.

Comment: Can't you use multiple files and merging after? You save a file in a temp directory for every chunk of the remote file and you merge everything after.

Comment: @JakubZaverka : It usually is. You can see the difference if you try downloading the same file using `wget` and a download manager like `DownThemAll` (for Firefox) or even try to Multi-Thread `wget` using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745799/multiple-wget-r-a-site-simultaneously).

Comment: @hurtledown : My question is, how do I download the **different parts of a single file**?

Comment: Here you have answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328059/how-to-create-partial-download-in-twisted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To download part of the file, just set the `Range` header like this

```
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.headers['Range'] = 'bytes=%s-%s' % (start, end)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Not all server support the `Range` header though. Most file sharing service don't.

Answer (score 5):

first, the http server should return Content-Length header. this is usually means the file is a static file, if it is a dynamic file, such as a result of php or jsp, you can not do such split.

then, you can use http Range header when request, this header tell the server which part of file should return. see python doc for how set and parse http head.

to do this, if the part size is 100k, you first request with Range: 0-1000000 100k will get first part, and in its conent-length in response tell your the size of file, then start some thread with different Range, it will work

Comment: Ive been searching for this answere for 6 months thank you

Answer (score 0):

See file.seek in http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects.

This might do the trick.

Out of interest, what is the reason behind splitting the file?

Comment: Its a **remotely hosted file** that I need to access. Not one on my system.