# FTP downloading freezes the whole application

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, ftplib

I'm trying to download a file from FTP server which is about 100 MB. It's a test .bin file because I'm testing the app and I guess the files I will want to download in the future will weight even more. When I want to download the file the whole application just freezes and then after a few seconds it downloads the file. The file is complete and it downloads it successfully without any errors or something like that. The only problem is the freeze.

My code:

```py
ftp = FTP('exampledomain.com')
ftp.login(user='user', passwd='password')

ftp.cwd('/main_directory/')

filename = '100MB.bin'

with open(filename, 'wb') as localfile:
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, localfile.write, 1024)

ftp.quit()
localfile.close()
```

I tried using `sleep()` between some lines of the code e.g between the logging in and downloading the file but it didn't help and it also seems that `sleep()` does not work AT ALL when working with FTP.

Comment: What do you mean by freeze? It's expected that if the file is being downloaded your scirpt will be blocked until the download is completed. Are you inside of a GUI that you need active while downloading? If so, then make the function async

Comment: @R10t-- I think I almost got it now here is my code:
```async def update_status(self):
        if connecting:
            await self.updateStatusText.setText("Status: Connecting...")
        elif downloading:
            await self.updateStatusText.setText("Status: Downloading...")
        elif downloaded:
            await self.updateStatusText.setText("Status: Updated!")
```
I get a TypeError:
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression.

Do you know what causes this error? I can't figure it out. I've 'awaited' everything and I'm using asyncio.

Comment: it seems `setText()` returns `None` so you have `await None`

Comment: `await` doesn't work with every function, it has to be [awaitable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables) function. For example it will not work with standard `time.sleep()`, it needs special `asyncio.sleep()`

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help. Do you know how can I make it another way so it does not freeze?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the file on another thread:

```
import threading
import time
from ftplib import FTP

def download():
    ftp = FTP('exampledomain.com')
    ftp.login(user='user', passwd='password')

    ftp.cwd('/main_directory/')

    filename = '100MB.bin'

    with open(filename, 'wb') as localfile:
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, localfile.write)

    ftp.quit()

print("Starting download...")

thread = threading.Thread(target=download)
thread.start()

print("Download started")

while thread.isAlive():
    print("Still downloading...")
    time.sleep(1)

print("Done")
```

---

*Based on:

[How to download a file over HTTP with multi-thread (asynchronous download) using Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33541956/850848)*

*Your followup question about modifying the code for PyQt:

[FTP download with text label showing the current status of the download](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57603694/850848)*

Comment: Thanks. It's simple and I understand it and I guess it would work with prints but I'm actually using PyQt 4 and the FTP download is started by a button and I want to change the text label. I forgot to mention it. Do I have to rewrite the code in like a different way or in PyQt 4 GUIs I have to use QThread?

Comment: See [Updating GUI elements in MultiThreaded PyQT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9957195/850848).

Comment: I'm quite new in Python and even more new in PyQt. I quite don't understand it. How do I convert the code to download file instead of URLs like in the question you linked?

Comment: Well, I'm new to Python as well and I do not know anything about PyQt. But I believe it's rather obvious how to modify the code. Anyway, how do you *"want to change the text label"*? What do you want to show there?

Comment: I want to show the status of the download e.g:
"Connecting...", 
"Downloading..."

Comment: Well I modified the code but It doesn't work so I guess I'm doing something wrong. I posted the code to hastebin so It's easier to read: https://hastebin.com/wilitamiye.rb

Comment: I've moved the PyQt answer to your other question.