# Does Python throttle individual bandwidth by default?

Tags: python, python-requests

- *My average download speed on the wifi I'm currently using runs up to 200 Megabits/s.*

I noticed that when downloading an `.mp4` file with `requests`:

My Code:

```py
with open(path, "wb") as f:
    for chunk in res.iter_content(1024):
        f.write(chunk)
```

In my Task Manager, it shows Python using only 8 Megabits/s on average when downloading this file.  I was just wondering if `Python` or `Requests` throttles download speeds by default when it comes to larger files.

Comment: no other application or program is using the internet at the same time?

Comment: have you tried fetching it via wget or curl?  the server for that particular resource may be doing the throttling.

Comment: @Charalamm Just discord but it isn't very bandwidth heavy.  Ultimately, Python seems to cap it at 8Mb/s no matter what I try.  I've even tried changing the `chunk_size` to something massive but that wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @JLPeyret I haven't tried `curl` yet.  How would I do so?  Is `curl` a python package or would I have to call from subprocess?  Are you referring to `pycurl`?

Comment: 1024 bytes is very small and gives much overhead. A modern computer should be able to process much larger chunks . Try  chunks of 10000, 50000 ... and look at the result.

Comment: Try taking a multithreaded approach, that's the way to do it.

Comment: @l'L'l how could I do so?  I've never worked with `multi-threading` before.

Comment: [This would be the basic idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33543751/499581), although there are tons of other ways to do it.

Comment: @l'L'l How does this work?  Is this just splitting the content of the download and using asynchronous requests?

Comment: curl is just a command line utility on Linux or macos to grab a file.   For example, after copying the address for the Subway image at https://www.bbc.com/news/technology-55279051, I just used `curl https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/52A1/production/_116035112_gettyimages-1175368406.jpg --output foo.jpg`  Now, if you point it to your file's URL and curl is also showing 8Mb/s then it's a server-side throttle, not a `requests` issue.  Now, if you're on Windows I don't know what to use, though Powershell seems to have some equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems that the host that I was downloading from was limiting the bandwidth for their public downloads to 1MB.  I've done some research on if Python limits bandwidth and I'm positive that it does not.